# Wordpress WooCommerce Product Carousel doesn't show pictures

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, caroufredsel

First of all, I'm not a coding wonder and a starter.

I've a problem that I'm trying to solve for a couple of days. It's about the carousel on WooCommerce. The website is tegelsenlaminaat.nl and an example is: http://www.tegelsenlaminaat.nl/product/hoomline-balmoral-xl-spa/

I get the following error: TypeError: v.carouFredSel is not a function. (In 'v.carouFredSel(w)', 'v.carouFredSel' is undefined)

How can I solve this and what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that you're making a call to the carouFredSel function before that function has been registered.

Basically you're trying to call that function before that function exists. It would appear the JavaScript file that creates that function isn't being output to your site.

If you're implementing that directly into your theme you need to make sure you're including the script that registers the function before your script.min.js script.

The github for that plugin has a script titled `jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js`. You could include that with your enqueued scripts, typically in your functions.php.

That would probably look something like this:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'caroufredsel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 6.2.1, true);`

`wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.min.js', array ( 'caroufredsel' ), 1.0, true);`

That would enqueue both the caroufredsel script if included in your theme's assets/js directory and caroufredsel is dependent on jQuery and your min scripts is dependent on both jQuery and caroufredsel.

For more on enqueing scripts check out [this article](https://jasonyingling.me/add-scripts-wordpress-themes-plugins-right-way/) from my site covering the topic.

Comment: When posting your link, please [explain it's your website](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) clearly in the post.

Comment: Updated with clarification. Thanks for letting me know.